# Custom Post Type and single-posttype template

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I created CPT **topic**

```
function wpse100_create_cpt() {
    register_post_type( 'topic', array(
        'labels' => array(
            //.....
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '/topic', 
            'with_front' => false
            ),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        ) );
add_action( 'init', 'wpse100_create_cpt' );
```

I choose permalink /%postname%, but by default URL mysite.tld/topic/postname, then I remove slug from URL  mysite.tld/postname uses this code

```
function wpse100_remove_slug($post_link, $post) {
    if ( 'topic' != $post->post_type )
        return $post_link;

    return str_replace(get_bloginfo('url') . '/topic' , get_bloginfo('url'), $post_link);
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse100_remove_slugs', 10, 2 );
```

and then create template for CPT single-topic.php but I get 404 error. How I can to correct the error?

PS If I turn off function `wpse100_remove_slug()` it works fine, but I need use URL such as mysite.tld/postname

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress 3.3 custom post type with /%postname%/ permastruct?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37650/wordpress-3-3-custom-post-type-with-postname-permastruct)

Comment: not a duplicate, because I found a different solution

Comment: The duplicity refers to the question not the answers. You seem to be wanting `example.com/%postname%` permalink structure for a custom post type. That's what the linked question addresses. Unfortunately it's not really something that can/should be done in WordPress - so I don't think there are any better answers than those given.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not leave answer to my question. Requires at least 100 reputation points. I'll write tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Big Thanks @Scribu [Alternative to query_posts for main loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/alternative-to-query-posts-for-main-loop/21378#21378) Now works fine and no more 404 error.

```
function wpse49295_alter_the_query( $request )
{
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query(); 
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_single() )
        $request['post_type'] = 'topic';

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse49295_alter_the_query' );
```